# How to change vite message displayed on CLI at server start

Tags: vue.js, command-line-interface, vite

I got a Vue project and start the server with `npm run dev`.

This will show a message on my CLI:

```
$ npm run dev

> @test/my-project@1.0.0 dev
> vite


  VITE v4.5.1  ready in 474 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://127.0.0.1:8096/scope
```

**Question:** Is there a possibilty to change the CLI message or add some text?

**Reason:** I want to display the actual URL instead of `localhost` or the IP.

Thanks to y'all!